# "I told he is fine" vs "I told he was fine"

Tags: tense, subordinate-clauses

Which sentence is grammatically correct in case he is still fine at the present time?

1. I told he is fine.
2. I told he was fine.

In school, I was told the tense of a subordinate clause must follow the tense of the main clause. In that case, #2 is the correct phrase, but native speakers typically use #1 as he is still fine? This confuses me a lot.

Comment: Neither is correct: *tell* in contexts like this requires an Indirect Object: *I told   **somebody** (that) he is/was fine*. The tense of the subordinate clause depends on what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with StoneyB here.  "told" needs an object.  (*I **told her that** he is fine* or *I **was told** he is fine*)  The verb tense depends a lot on whatever the main clause was.

- When my teacher asked me, I **told her** he **was** fine.
- My teacher will ask me and I **will tell her** he **is** fine.
- My teacher asks me every day and **I tell her** he **is** fine.

However, without an object is more natural and correct to use "said" here.

*I **said** he **is** fine.*

*I **said** he **was** fine.*

Answer (score 1):

Along with the other answers and comments (and no, neither of yours are correct), there is another possibility: *I am told* or *I was told.* The four possibilities are:

> I am told that he is fine.
>   I am told that he was fine.
>   I was told that he is fine.
>   I was told that he was fine.

All of these have different meanings, and the differences are straightforward.  I'll add a little context to make the meanings more obvious:

> How is he? I am told that he is fine.
>   How is he? I am told that he was fine as of last week.
>   How is he? I was told last night that he is fine. (Presumably, he still is.)
>   How is he? I was told last week that he was fine as of then.

To make it a little easier, you can substitute *I hear* for *I am told* or *I heard* for *I was told*, without changing the meaning at all:

> I hear that he is fine.
>   I hear that he was fine.
>   I heard that he is fine.
>   I heard that he was fine.

To answer your question directly, any sentence that includes *he is fine* in it means that he is still fine at the present time. If it includes *he was fine*, he may or may not be still fine at the present time.

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are incorrect grammatically as there's no indirect object after the verb "told"; the verb tell always takes an indirect object after it, for example:

I told her (that) he was fine.

I told her (that) he is fine.

As the statement is true and up to date, backshift is optional.  You can use either is or was in the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct within the context of you example that the tense of the subordinate clause should follow the tense of the main clause.  Since "told" is past tense, you should use "was."

> I was told that he was fine.

In my own experience, only native speakers whose profession is the English language consistently make few if any mistakes when speaking.  The rest of us make mistakes all the time.  I can easily imagine the average person on the street saying...

> I was told he's fine.

But I have also literally heard people say...

> They tol' me he be good.

Which is English so atrocious that angles weep to hear it.

Therefore, I do not recommend using spoken English as a measure of correct English.

Comment: -1 for unqualified *Since "told" is past tense, you **should** use "was""* (boldtext mine). It's true someone might say *I told them I was gay*. But he *might also* say *I told them I **am** gay.* And his choice of tense *might* be affected by intended nuance.

Comment: Furthermore, there is "I am told that he is fine." The past participle is not always past tense, as it forms part of the passive voice in the present tense as well.